# Trying to backup or copy a Google Sheet into a specific folder and keep getting "Cannot find method addFile(Folder). (line 25, file "XXXXX")"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I keep getting the following error with my code.

"Cannot find method addFile(Folder). (line 25, file "XXXXX")"

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much!

```
function manualBackup() {
var folder, backup;
folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B49siU2r7QqYSE9ZeHJCM2FKR2c");
backup = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + "_Backup_Copy");
backup = DriveApp.addFile(folder); // This is line 25 with the issue
backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
}
```

Comment: As per your requirement this line "backup = DriveApp.addFile(folder);" should be "folder.addFile(backup)". Try changing it and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested this code:

```
function manualBackup() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B3M-kyknQTApWG1STzBhaFBEMVE");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1mBWb98eap8xyAjlahCV8TM3FVKabvoM3OdesICRdERg");
  var name = file.getName() + "_Backup_Copy";
  file.makeCopy(name ,folder);
}
```

Seems that addFile() or makeCopy() methods will be working only for folders where you have write permission granted. Tried this code on a folder which is created by me in my Drive.

Hope that helps!